# Regarding temp data storage in android

Tags: android, mysql

I am creating an android project. And in my android project I have 4 screen which consists of seekbars. So from each screen I will get the 2 values and the total values will be 8 values after the the 4 screen. and I will be storing these 8 values in my database.

But My problem how send the 8 values at at a time to database. 
I got an idea of doing it like storing values comming from each screen and sending all the values at a time to the database but I could not succeed it doing.
So can any help to it in an easy way.

My database looks like

```
Name Sc1a Sc1b  Sc2a sc2b Sc3a sc3b sc4a sc4b timestamp(current)
stud1 10   30    40    50   60  70  80    90   2-8-2013 14:00:00
```

Where the values sc1a,sc1b will come from screen1 and sc2a,sc2b comes from screen2 and sc3a,sc3b comes from screen3 
And finally on screen I will values sc4a,sc4b and by including all the values from 4 screens that is sc1a,sc1b,sc2a,sc2b,sc3a,sc3b,sc4a,sc4b to the database table at a time which includes current time stamp.

Comment: Provide more info about how are those 8 fields mapped in your database? what is it that you are using to store single value in database, can you modify that logic like pass more parameters etc/

Answer (score 0):

Store each screen's values in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). When you at the last screen, read stored values, build your query with all these values and execute, storing in DB.

Comment: can you provide me with any example.